# Exporting Rule Project from ILOG Decision Center

Tags: ilog, ibm-odm

Every time I try to export my rule project from decision center I am getting the following error:

```
Error: An unknown error occurred while trying to perform this operation:
 ilog.rules.synchronization.SyncException: null
```

I am not getting this error when I export other rule projects, so it's not a decision center related problem it's probably a rule project problem.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. This happens when you have rules under your main rule folder and not in it's proper rule package. Simply delete or move the rules sitting directly inside of the rules folder.